# "Шутка юмора"

Tags: фразеология

Кто-нибудь может объяснить значение и применение выражения? По отдельности слова понятны.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это искусственное образование, умышленная тавтологичность, масло масляное. Изначально именно такой "шуткой юмора" и было, но, как чаcто бывает, стало восприниматься многими как нечто осмысленное и нормативное.

Предположительно: впервые прозвучало в каком-то из КВНов первой эпохи (в 60-х или начале 70-х).

Comment: А ещё говорят "морда лица". Глупо, но смешно))).

Comment: С "мордой лица", боюсь, будет несколько сложнее. И интереснее. 
Во-первых, никем такая конструкция как нормативная не рассматривается.
Во-вторых можно рассматривать как своеобразный ответ народа на неумное использования "лица" в чиновничьей и жкрналистской речи. От "физического лица" до "лица кавказской национальности"; в те годы было еще более популярно "лицо еврейской национальности", что вообще уже не имело под собой никакой мотивации. 
Есть смутное предположение, что вся шутка могла родиться как раз из "морды лица еврейской национальности". Вслушайтесь, звучит убийственно!